# Converting Java to Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to learn Scala, so can anyone tell me how to convert the following in scala:

```
for (int t = 0; true; t++)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The Java code you presented is the head declaration of an infinite loop, which counts the variable `t` upwards, starting from zero. But you left out the body of the loop. What is your loop supposed to do? When will it stop?

Comment: Oddly enough, i think this is something which is *more* natural in Scala than in Java - in Scala, you can write this as an iteration (or a mapping or whatever) over an infinite collection containing the natural numbers.

Answer (score 19):

With imperative style you can write (as you do in Java):

```
var t = 0
while(true) {
  t+=1
  ...
}
```

With lazy functional this could be:

```
def ints(n: Int = 0): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(n, ints(n+1))
ints().map(t => ...)
```

Using built-in functions:

```
Iterator.from(0).map ( t => .... )
```

The common use case with such infinite structures, is to take infinite stream or iterator, perform some operations on it, and then take number of results:

```
Iterator.from(0).filter(t => t % 1 == 0).map(t => t*t).take(10).toList
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no `++` method on `Int` in Scala, you should write `t += 1` instead of `t++`.

Comment: I'd use `foreach` instead of `map`, since the latter creates a new collection, so will eat memory particularly if what you're doing is infinite, i.e. `Iterator from 0 foreach { t => ... }`.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge yes, I though the same (the [first version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10498295/1) of answer was with foreach), but then I though that side effects with infinite structures is a dangerous thing, especially for novice

Answer (score 8):

As I mentioned in the comments, your question does not seem to make much sense - please add more detail.

For now, the closest Scala translation I can come up with would be:

`Stream from 0`

Comment: That does much more than OP's code. I propose `while (true)` :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use while or for.

You can use for

```
for(i<-0 to 100) {
  println(i)
}
```

or you use until when you want to increment by N number

```
for(i <- 5 until 55 by 5) {
    println(i)
}
```

or you better use while

```
var i = 0
while(true) {
  ...
  i+=1
}
```

or also do-while

```
var i = 0
do {
    ...
    i += 1
} while(true)
```

Have a look at : http://www.simplyscala.com/
and test it out by yourself

Also, in my blog I did some posts about imperative scala where I used for and while loops you can have a look there.

http://carlosqt.blogspot.com/search/label/Scala

Answer (score 2):

A simple for comprehension in scala looks mostly this way:

```
for (i <- 0 until 10) {
  // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend telling people to use for-comprehension as a surrogate for `for` loops.

Comment: I agree with you, but I thought this might be something he can start with.

Comment: I don't see the problem; using while-loops instead seems like premature optimization. (*Programming in Scala* refers to for-expressions without a `yield` as "for-loops", so it seems they were intended to be used as such.)